# vim updated status line with external command

Tags: unix, vim

Is it possible to have a dynamic statusline which evaluates an external shell command? Specifically I want to read part of the line from a pipe.

I.e. some independent program writes status messages to a unix pipe (or say some conventional file). I want the vim to read this file and its status line to display the message whenever the file changes.

Comment: please consider editing your posting to include an example of what you intend. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call `date` command in status line:

```
:set statusline=%{system('date')}
```

You can change `date` to your external command.